# I can't see an image in my Silverlight 5 project

Tags: image, visual-studio-2012, silverlight-5.0, expression-blend

When I started my Silverlight 5 project, I put an image with an animation (I did in Blend) on my main menu, it worked very well. Then I went forward in my project and I did not realize exactly at which moment I stopped seeing my image and animation.

I did a test **on my project**, creating a **new user control**, which only has the image and the animation, and **it doesn't work**, then I made a **new project** and put the image and the animation on the main page, **and it works**!

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on in my original project that prevents me from seeing the Image and animation?

Thanks a lot

An example, on my SilverlightControl1.xaml:

`

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Mtto2Animacion" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="False">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" Storyboard.TargetName="image2">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="55.77"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="-0.217"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="BackgroundMTTO" ImageSource="Imagenes/MTTOBackground.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="IMGBannerPradera" ImageSource="Imagenes/BannerPradera.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Image x:Name="image2" Margin="5" Source="Imagenes/MTTO2.png" Loaded="image2_Loaded">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

`

And on my SilverlightControl1.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MTTO
{
    public partial class SilverlightControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public SilverlightControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void image2_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Mtto2Animacion.Begin(); 
        }
    }
}
```

This is my image (MTTO2.png)

[image: this is my image (MTTO2.png)]

Comment: You're probably going to need to share some code for us to see. It could be something simple like just an image path, or not firing off your storyboard, or the build action of the image, or a number of things. Without being able to re-create it though it's a tough one to guess about by just the description you've given.

Comment: I added an example to my post

Comment: When I run my original App with this UserControl, don't work, but if I create a new Project and Add this existing element (the UserControl SilverlightControl1) and I run it, it works

Comment: when I say "that does not work", I mean that I can't even see the image, much less animation, at run time, but at design time I can see the image

Comment: If you look at the properties of the image file, do you have the Build Action set to 'Content'

Comment: Chris W. thanks, sorry for delay...yes, I see at my Project, and for the image file MTTO2.png I have Build Action = Content

Comment: Chris W. thank you very much!! I inspected all my image files used at my MainPage, and I set all as 'Resource' at Property, and it Works!! Do you know where I can learn how this property works? What does each of the options? thanks a lot again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris W. thank you very much!! I inspected all my image files used at my MainPage, and I set all as **'Resource'** at **Build Action** Property, and it Works!! Do you know where I can learn how this property works? What does each of the options? thanks a lot again

Comment: Just give something like "visual studio file build action property" a quick google, you should find anything you need pretty quick. Glad you found your remedy, cheers! :)